# Brave Hector starting stats

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I just downloaded the game and choose the free Brave Hector from the free summon.

When I look at website or wiki of FEH, they all show a starting attack of 10/11/12 maybe I am off by 1 but yet the stats on my Hector has 27 attack

I don't understand how that works, can someone explain this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hector you chose has neutral stats, meaning he has no boon or bane. That’s how all freebie units are (like Grand Hero Battle heroes or Tempest Trial rewards).

The reason he has 27 attack is that his weapon is 16 mt on top of his neutral 11 Atk. 16 + 11 = 27.

Comment: Ok yes I unequipped his weapon and indeed the numbers go down, everything makes sense now thanks